# How can I copy files to a docker container when error happened:Nosuch container?

Tags: docker, centos

I am new about docker, so ,if any wrong thoughts come from me ,please point out it.Thanks~

I aim at running a web server that was developed by me ,or a team I belong to,in the docker.

So, I thought out three steps:

Have a image ,copy the web files into it,and run the  container.so,I do the step below:

1- get a docker image.

I try like this : `docker pull centos`, so that I can get a image based on centos.Here, I did not care about the version of centos,of course, it's version is 6.7 or ,just taged:latest.

Here,I check the image by `docker images`,and I can see it like this:

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
docker.io/centos    latest              d123f4e55e12        3 weeks ago         196.6 MB
```

So,I think this step successed.

2- try copying the files in local system to the container.

I stop at the path: /tornado,which had a folder named fordocker .The

fordocker contains the web-server files.

I try commonds like this(based on the guide):

```
docker cp fordocker/ d123f4e55e12:/web
```

But! Here comes the error:

```
Error response from daemon: No such container: d123f4e55e12
```

3- if I copy the files successfully,I could try like this:`docker run -d centos xxx python web.py`.

This step will come error?I don't know yet.

I searched a lot ,but do not explain the phenomenon.

It seemed that everyone,beside me ,use the commond would succes.

So,here comes the questions:

1- Is the method I thought out feasible? Must I create a images through profile?

2- Where comes the error if the method is feasible? Did the commond cp based on otherthings that I had not done?

3- What should I do if the method is not feasible?Create a image myself?

Have a good day~

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have docker images and docker container. That is different.

You pull or build images.

When you launch an image, it becomes a running container.

An image is not a running container, and so, you will not be able to copy a file inside an image.

I do not know if this what you want to do, but you may

1) launch an image

`docker run ...`

2) copy or modify a file

`docker ps`

shows your running container, and so you can

`docker cp...`

a file inside this running container

3) maybe save this modified image with

`docker commit...`

But usually, if you want to modify an image, you modify the Dockerfile, and so you can easily build a new image with such a command

`docker build -t myuser/myimage:321 .`

Notice the final dot, it means you use the Dockerfile that is local.

See for example a Dockerfile for Nginx

https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/c8bfb9b5260d4ad308deac5343b73b027f684375/mainline/stretch/Dockerfile

Comment: Good morning,  honour getting your answer at the beginning of my day. Exactly, I did not take differents between images and  container. As before , I just think images is the container in the server, and the differents of them is that if it is in my computer. Certenly,after your explain,I konw I had thinked a wrong way. By the hand, I just want to try deploying a  python web project by docker, the guide told two ways.First,born a Dcokerfile.Second,pull a images and try to change it and save.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I  aimed at  deploying a python web project by docker,and the first method I thought about is :copy server files to a container and run it with `python ***.py`.

But I did not get the difference between images and container.

Also,I got some other methods:

1- build a Dcokerfile. By this way,we can run a image with out other commond like `python ***.py` because we can write the commond into the Dcokerfile.

2- get a image that has a right python version,and try like `docker run  -v $PWD/myapp:/usr/src/myapp  -w /usr/src/myapp python:3.5 python helloworld.py`,but need not  copy files to the container.

If all the methods can I master, I would choose to build a Dcokerfile?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#build-the-app
I born a Dcokerfile follow the guide ,and it successed.
Nice day